# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'queue_pb2'

Tags: python, flask, grpc, grpc-python

I am currently trying to implement grpc with flask (grpc as a server and flask as the client side) but I keep facing this issue: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'queue_pb2' when I am trying to run the command 'flask run' in the terminal.

This is my current directory structure:

```
Cloud/
|-- app.py
|-- microservices/
    |-- queue/
    |-- protos/
        |-- queue.proto
    |-- queue_pb2.py
    |-- queue_pb2_grpc.py
```

This is the command I used in my terminal to generate the pb2 files in the microservices/queue directory

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I protos --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. protos/queue.proto
```

This is my current code from app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, request
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
import grpc
from microservices.queue.queue_pb2 import CheckInResponse, CheckOutResponse, CleanupQueueResponse, GetQueueCountResponse, CheckInRequest, CheckOutRequest, CleanupQueueRequest, GetQueueCountRequest
from microservices.queue.queue_pb2_grpc import QueueStub

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxx'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///../db/mall.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)

# Create Queue table
class Queue(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    check_in = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    @classmethod
    def cget_user_by_username(cls, username):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    @classmethod
    def add_user(cls, username, check_in_time):
        new_user = cls(username=username, check_in=check_in_time)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def remove_user(cls, user):
        db.session.delete(user)
        db.session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def cleanup_queue(cls, threshold_time):
        cls.query.filter(cls.check_in <= threshold_time).delete()
        db.session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def get_queue_count(cls):
        return cls.query.count()
```

This is my queue.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package queue;

message CheckInRequest {
  string username = 1;
}

message CheckInResponse {
  string message = 1;
}

message CheckOutRequest {
  string username = 1;
}

message CheckOutResponse {
  string message = 1;
}

message CleanupQueueRequest {}

message CleanupQueueResponse {
  string message = 1;
}

message GetQueueCountRequest {}

message GetQueueCountResponse {
  int32 count = 1;
}

service Queue {
  rpc CheckIn (CheckInRequest) returns (CheckInResponse);
  rpc CheckOut (CheckOutRequest) returns (CheckOutResponse);
  rpc CleanupQueue (CleanupQueueRequest) returns (CleanupQueueResponse);
  rpc GetQueueCount (GetQueueCountRequest) returns (GetQueueCountResponse);
}
```

This is a snippet of the queue_pb2_grpc.py as you can see the line import queue_pb2 as queue__pb2 is there

```
# Generated by the gRPC Python protocol compiler plugin. DO NOT EDIT!
"""Client and server classes corresponding to protobuf-defined services."""
import grpc

import queue_pb2 as queue__pb2


class QueueStub(object):
    """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

    def __init__(self, channel):
        """Constructor.

        Args:
            channel: A grpc.Channel.
        """
        self.CheckIn = channel.unary_unary(
                '/queue.Queue/CheckIn',
                request_serializer=queue__pb2.CheckInRequest.SerializeToString,
                response_deserializer=queue__pb2.CheckInResponse.FromString,
                )
        self.CheckOut = channel.unary_unary(
                '/queue.Queue/CheckOut',
                request_serializer=queue__pb2.CheckOutRequest.SerializeToString,
                response_deserializer=queue__pb2.CheckOutResponse.FromString,
                )
        self.CleanupQueue = channel.unary_unary(
                '/queue.Queue/CleanupQueue',
                request_serializer=queue__pb2.CleanupQueueRequest.SerializeToString,
                response_deserializer=queue__pb2.CleanupQueueResponse.FromString,
                )
        self.GetQueueCount = channel.unary_unary(
                '/queue.Queue/GetQueueCount',
                request_serializer=queue__pb2.GetQueueCountRequest.SerializeToString,
                response_deserializer=queue__pb2.GetQueueCountResponse.FromString,
                )
```

Any advice would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this for quite some time thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Revise this import statement `import queue_pb2 as queue__pb2` as `microservices.queue_pb2_grpc import queue__pb2`

Comment: Did you mean in the queue_pb2_grpc.py file instead of import queue_pb2 as queue__pb2 do: from microservices.queue_pb2_grpc import queue__pb2? I've tried it it dosen't work

Comment: Yes in queue_pb2_grpc.py. I am surprised that it didn't work. Can you try these:
1. "import microservices.queue_pb2_grpc as queue__pb2"
2. "import Cloud.microservices.queue_pb2_grpc as queue__pb2"

Comment: Nope it dosen't work too. All i got was no module named "cloud' and no module named "queue_pb2_grpc"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by calling D:\GitHub Repo\Cloud> python -m microservices.queue.queue_server